# Return the number of words over min length and Replace ones that arent with word + spaces

Tags: python, list, testing, replace, counter

For any name whose length is less than the min_length, replace that item of the list with a new string containing the original name with the space(s) added to the right-hand side to achieve the minimum length
example: min_length = 5 /// 'dog' after the change = 'dog  '
and also Return the amount of names that were originally over the min_length in the list

```
def pad_names(list_of_names, min_length):  
    '''(list of str, int) -> int  
    Return the number of names that are longer than the minimum length.  
    >>> pad_names(list_of_names, 5)  
        2  
    '''  
    new_list = []  
    counter = 0  
    for word in list_of_names:      
        if len(word) > min_length:  
            counter = counter + 1  

    for word in list_of_names:  
        if len(word) < min_length:  
            new_list.append(word.ljust(min_length))  
        else:  
            new_list.append(word)  
     return(counter)
```

I currently am getting 5 errors on this function:

all errors are #incorrect return value

test_02: pad_names_one_name_much_padding_changes_list
Cause: The list is not changed correctly for the case of 1 name needing padding

test_04: pad_names_one_name_needs_one_pad_changes_list
Cause: one name needs one pad changes list

test_10: pad_names_all_padded_by_3_changes_list
Cause:all padded by 3 changes list

test_12: pad_names_all_padded_different_amounts_changes_list
Cause: all padded different amounts changes list

test_20: pad_names_one_empty_name_list_changed
Cause: one empty name list changed

This function does not need to be efficient just needs to pass those tests without creating more problems

Comment: Provide us with output - then it will be easier to understand what do you need

Comment: return(smth) is a bad thing)

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in spirit with how you've written this, I'm guessing you want to be modifying the list of names so the result can be checked (as well as returning the count)...

```
def test(names, minlen):
    counter = 0
    for idx, name in enumerate(names):
        newname = name.ljust(minlen)
        if newname != name:
            names[idx] = newname 
        else:
            counter += 1
    return counter
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
def pad_names(list_of_names, min_length):  
    counter = 0
    for i, val in enumerate(list_of_names):      
        if len(val) >= min_length:  
            counter += 1  
        elif len(val) < min_length:  
            list_of_names[i] = val.ljust(min_length)
    return counter
```

OR:

```
def pad_names(words, min_length):  
    i, counter = 0, 0
    for val in words:
        if len(val) >= min_length:  
            counter += 1  
        elif len(val) < min_length:  
            words[i] = val.ljust(min_length)
        i += 1
    return counter
```

Comment: We have not used enumerate so I don't think my teacher will allow use to use it.

Comment: it's a base function - in any case will add sample with counter

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand your question, but here is a fairly pythonic way to do what I think you want:

```
data = ['cat', 'snake', 'zebra']

# pad all strings with spaces to 5 chars minimum
#  uses string.ljust for padding and a list comprehension
padded_data = [d.ljust( 5, ' ' ) for d in data]

# get the count of original elements whose length was 5 or great
ct = sum( len(d) >= 5 for d in data )
```

Comment: Not sure about `sum( len(d) >= 5 for d in data )` - I'd write that as `sum(1 for d in data if len(d) >= 5)`

Answer (score 0):

[string.ljust()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ljust) is a quick and simple way to pad strings to a minimum length.

Here's how I would write the function:

```
def pad_names(list_of_names, min_length):
   # count strings that meets the min_length requirement
   count = sum(1 for s in list_of_names if len(s) > min_length) 
   # replace list with updated content, using ljust() to pad strings
   list_of_names[:] = [s.ljust(min_length) for s in list_of_names]

   return count  # return num of strings that exceeds min_length
```

While succinct, that may not be the most efficient approach for large datasets since we're essentially creating a new list and copying it over the new one.

If performance is an issue, I'd go with a loop and only update the relevant entries.

```
def pad_names(list_of_names, min_length):
   count = 0
   for i, s in enumerate(list_of_names):
      if len(s) > min_length:   # should it be >= ??
          count += 1  # increment counter
      else:
         list_of_names[i] = s.ljust(min_length)  # update original list
   return count
```

Comment: The loop isn't required here... `list_of_names[:] = [word.ljust(min_length) for word in list_of_names]` will do it